# Separate Dataframe column into multiple columns based on regex parameter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

Pandas noob here. What would be the best way to remove each teams record and place it into a new column? Thanks in advance!

```
    Rank    Team    
0   1       LA Rams (5-0)   
1   2       New Orleans (4-1)   
2   3       New England (3-2)   
3   4       Kansas City (5-0)   
4   5       Pittsburgh (2-2-1)  
5   6       Baltimore (3-2)
```

Comment: `df[['Team', 'record']] = df.Team.str.rsplit(' ', n=1, expand=True)` should be slightly more efficient since it doesn't use regex.

Comment: @Abdou Nice one, although it is a bit less flexible if teams with more complex names are introduced.

Comment: Ah very nice, thank you both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question.

Unfortunately, [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) would fetch the record quite easily, but will not remove it (Using a naive regex, feel free to use a more sophisticated one in case a team has `(...)` in its name):

```
df['Record'] = df['Team'].str.extract('(\(.*?\))')
print(df)
#    Rank                Team   record
#  0    1       LA Rams (5-0)    (5-0)
#  1    2   New Orleans (4-1)    (4-1)
#  2    3   New England (3-2)    (3-2)
#  3    4   Kansas City (5-0)    (5-0)
#  4    5  Pittsburgh (2-2-1)  (2-2-1)
#  5    6     Baltimore (3-2)    (3-2)
```

This will require implementing our own function:

```
import re

record_regex = re.compile(r'(\(.*?\))')

records = []

def extract_and_remove_record(x):
    record = record_regex.findall(x)[0]
    records.append(record)
    return record_regex.sub('', x)

df['Team'] = df['Team'].apply(extract_and_remove_record)
df['Record'] = records

print(df)
#    Rank          Team  Records
#  0    1      LA Rams     (5-0)
#  1    2  New Orleans     (4-1)
#  2    3  New England     (3-2)
#  3    4  Kansas City     (5-0)
#  4    5   Pittsburgh   (2-2-1)
#  5    6    Baltimore     (3-2)
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! This has been making my hangover so much worse :D you rock @DeepSpace

Answer (score 0):

Another way without involving regex trick.

```
df[['Team Name', 'Team Records']] = d.Team.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.rstrip(')').split(' (')))
df.drop('Team', axis=1, inplace=True)
```